# How to parse selected expressions until an end keyword in pyparsing

Tags: pyparsing

I am parsing a verilog file to extract the dependencies within it.  I don't need to parse most of the module contents, but am only interested in include statements and module instantiations.  I first am attempting to only extract the include statements. This is my code so far:

```
include_pragma = Group(Keyword("`include") + quotedString + lineEnd.suppress())
module_definition = ZeroOrMore(~Keyword("endmodule") + MatchFirst([include_pragma, restOfLine])) + Keyword("endmodule")
```

My point is that I will either match an include pragma, or a line of anything until I reach "endmodule".  If I try this grammer on the following string, pyparsing gets into some kind of infinite loop.

```
`include "InternalInclude.v"

localparam COMMA_WIDTH = 10;

localparam  UNKNOWN = 1'b0,
            KNOWN   = 1'b1;

reg     [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] TtiuPosQ2;
reg                      TtiuDetQ2;
reg     [           7:0] TtiuDetQ2Save;

assign DebugQO = {  DataQI,         // 65:34
                    TxTrainingEnQI, // 33
                    TtiuDetQ2,      // 32
                    TtiuPosQ2       // 31:0
                  };

always @(posedge Clk or posedge ResetI) begin
    if (ResetI) begin
        CommaPosQO <= {(DATA_WIDTH){1'b0}};
        CommaDetQO <= 0;
        CommaPosQ1 <= {(DATA_WIDTH){1'b0}};
        CommaPosQ2 <= {(DATA_WIDTH){1'b0}};
        CommaDetQ2 <= 0;
        StateQ <= 0;

        CommaPosSaveQ <= {(DATA_WIDTH){1'b0}};
        TtiuPosQ1 <= 0;
        TtiuPosQ2 <= 0;
        TtiuDetQ2 <= 0;
        TtiuDetQ2Save <= 8'h00;
    end
    else begin 
        CommaPosQO <= CommaPosC2;
        CommaDetQO <= CommaDetC2;
        CommaPosQ1 <= CommaPosC;
        CommaPosQ2 <= CommaPosQ1;
        CommaDetQ2 <= (| CommaPosQ1);
        StateQ <= StateC;
        CommaPosSaveQ <= CommaPosSaveC;
        TtiuPosQ1 <= TtiuPosC1;
        TtiuPosQ2 <= TtiuPosC2;
        TtiuDetQ2 <= TtiuDetC2;
        TtiuDetQ2Save <= TtiuDetQ2 ? 8'hFF : {1'b0, TtiuDetQ2Save[7:1]};
    end
end

endmodule
```

I am probably misunderstanding the ~ operator.  Any suggestions?

**update**

After using the setDebug() method suggested, I found that the infinite loops prints this:

```
Match {Group:({"`include" quotedString using single or double quotes Suppress:(lineEnd)}) | Re:('.*')} at loc 0(1,1)
Matched {Group:({"`include" quotedString using single or double quotes Suppress:(lineEnd)}) | Re:('.*')} -> [['`include'
, '"InternalInclude.v"']]
Match {Group:({"`include" quotedString using single or double quotes Suppress:(lineEnd)}) | Re:('.*')} at loc 31(4,1)
Matched {Group:({"`include" quotedString using single or double quotes Suppress:(lineEnd)}) | Re:('.*')} -> ['']
Match {Group:({"`include" quotedString using single or double quotes Suppress:(lineEnd)}) | Re:('.*')} at loc 31(4,1)
Matched {Group:({"`include" quotedString using single or double quotes Suppress:(lineEnd)}) | Re:('.*')} -> ['']
Match {Group:({"`include" quotedString using single or double quotes Suppress:(lineEnd)}) | Re:('.*')} at loc 31(4,1)
Matched {Group:({"`include" quotedString using single or double quotes Suppress:(lineEnd)}) | Re:('.*')} -> ['']
```

Is something that I do causing the parse position not to move forward?

Comment: Change `Or` to `MatchFirst`, you are doing extra work with `Or` when you match an include directive, and in fact are probably doing testing that you *don't* want to do. 

You can monitor the parsing activity of a particular expression using `setDebug()`.  `setDebug` will report every attempt at parsing, and then report whether the parse succeeded or failed. Try changing `restOfLine` in your grammar to `restofLine.setDebug()` and see if this output is helpful.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I tried what you said and got the output as shown in my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with using the restOfLine expression.  It can match anything, including ''.  So, the parser would proceed as follows:

1. Matched `include "InternalInclude.v"`
2. Match '' to restOfLine
3. Match the same '' to restOfLine because it did not consume the \n AND there is still '' left before the \n, as there alwasy will be ;)

To fix it, I changed `restOfLine` to `(restOfLine + lineEnd)`.  This forced the parser to consume the \n after matching the line.  The new parser reads:

```
include_pragma = Group(Keyword("`include") + quotedString + lineEnd.suppress())
module_definition = ZeroOrMore(~Keyword("endmodule") + MatchFirst([include_pragma, (restOfLine + lineEnd)])) + Keyword("endmodule")
```

Comment: You might also look into using scanString or searchString instead of parseString. scan/searchString are useful when you are only trying to pick out pieces of a file, and not parse the whole thing. I think you might even get away with just `(include_pragma | Keyword("endmodule")).scanString(verilog_text)`.